# C++ Threadpool without using boost lib

Tags: c++, threadpool

I have to use a threadpool in my program but I have no idea how to use it. I know how to create and use a thread but after a lot of research, I can't find how can I implement a threadpool without using boost lib (forbidden). If you have some ideas or searching path, I will appreciate it.
I'm not asking for a full code but at least if you can lead me.

Comment: What OS are you targeting ?

Comment: A threadpool in its simplest form is just a collection of threads (or possible threads). When you have some work to do, you tell one of the thread in the collection to start doing that work.

Comment: Why forbid boost ? Manage thread without boost is like try to code without loops. :-D

Comment: I'm working on linux

Comment: @Caduchon Because it's a school project and we have some restrictions :/

Comment: Side comment: Depending on why you need a thread pool and If you are using newer C++ standard, like Cx11, although not a requirement, at least in MSVS, standard C++ calls to say async() are thread pooled. I'm guessing same holds on linux compilers.

Comment: Ok so you think that I have to create my threads and make them asynchronous using async() method ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just googled 20 seconds and I've found this, hope it helps, since your question is how to use threadpool

[C++ Thread Pool](http://stackoverflo)

**EDIT:**

Without boost:
[Simple thread pool in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/simple-thread-pool-in-c)

However this thread has "HOMEWORK" written all over it. Good luck ;)

Comment: This code is using "namespace boost::threadpool;", boost lib is forbidden in my project. I'd already found this code :s

Comment: you could try to look at the boost implementation to get some ideas for your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a production ready thread pool I had written long ago in C++. [C++ Plugin Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26078/A-C-Plug-in-ThreadPool-Design) using the Command Pattern and Chain of Responsibility pattern. Has quite a bit of advanced C++ like functors etc which may feel bit difficult to read.